# ElasticBeanstalk - Adding ec2-user to another group

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a cron job that needs to be run under `ec2-user` on my EC2 instance and it needs to be able to write to the standard log files for my web app. However, the log files are owned by `webapp` (as per normal).

I've successfully changed the permissions on the log files so that they are accessible by both the owner and the group `webapp:webapp`. But where I'm running into trouble is when I try to add the `ec2-user` to the `webapp` group.

I can do it fine in SSH with `sudo usermod -a -G webapp ec2-user` but when I try to add this command via EB **container-commands**, I get an error saying that `you must have a tty to run sudo`. Running the command without sudo gives me `/bin/sh: usermod: command not found`.

Anybody know of any other way to be able to add `ec2-user` to the `webapp` group via the Elastic Beanstalk deployment config.

Comment: Thank heavens you asked exactly what I was searching for. Please consider accepting the correct answer tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need to run this command from a container_command before executing any commands with sudo:](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=395894)

```
echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers
```

In context (in .ebextensions/yourconf.config)

```
container_commands:
  001-enableroot:
    command: echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers #disables error related to needing a tty for sudo, allows running without cli
```

Comment: I can't say for sure if this is an answer as the specific project that I needed this for has been taken out of my hands, but on reading the documentation at http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html#x5355444f455253204f5054494f4e53 it seems very likely.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure about the issue with the sudoers file, but generally a cleaner way to add a user to a group (than manually executing a command) is to use the `users` section of the `.ebextensions` file. For example, in `.ebextensions/something.config`:

```
users:
  ec2-user:
    groups:
      - webapp
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use sudo, the deploy script is ran by root.

Also, this is a server command, do it in the commands section instead of container commands section.

```
commands:
  01_set_user_role:
    command: "usermod -a -G webapp ec2-user"
```